# Can I use a variable to store a channel ID to be called later? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot that will take a message from one channel and send it to another. Currently this is my code

```
  linkchannel = message.channel.topic
  print(linkchannel)
  await asyncio.sleep(1)
  channel = client.get_channel(linkchannel)
  await channel.send('{} : {}'.format(message.author.name, message.content))
  await client.process_commands(message)
```

The channel id is stored in the channel topic, but the variable is not working as the argument for getting the channel. If I put the channel ID  in it works just fine but for this I really need it to be controlled by a variable. Anyone know how to use the variable to get the number or make it possible to get the channel through the variable?

Comment: What got printed?

Comment: The correct number got printed, I don't believe it had any whitespace, It seems like it thinks it is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, all it was is that I had to specify the variable should be an Int. Declaring the variable needed to be

```
linkchannel = int(message.channel.topic)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best answer would be just

```py
linkchannel=message.channel.id
```